# Probability measure and integral

Tags: real-analysis, measure-theory

Let $f:X$ $\longrightarrow$ $\mathbb{C}$, $f$ $\in$$L^1(\mu)$ where $(X,\mathcal{M},\mu)$ is a measure space and $\mu$ is a probability measure.

We can easily see that  $(\int$$|f|d\mu)^2$ $\leqslant$$\int|f|^2d\mu$.

Is it necessary, for this inequality to hold,that  $f$ is integrable?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is the Cauchy-Schwarz inequality. If $f$ is square integrable, that is, if $|f|^2$ is integrable, it shows that $|f|$ is integrable. If $f$ is not square integrable, then the right hand side is equal to $\infty$, and the inequality still holds.